# MVC 5 - How to update file and return success message?

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc, file, upload

I've tried Ajax.BeginForm, but does it not work.

With Ajax.BeginForm, the file arrives in null.

Now I'm trying to solve the problem with Html.BeginForm, the image also comes null.

What am I doing wrong?

**_Upload.cshtml:**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Upload</h4>
</div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{

@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">

            <div class="col-xs-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Image, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "file" })
            </div>
        </div>      


        <center><div id="result"></div></center>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="btn btn-success" value="Update" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>

        <script>

    $(function () {

        $("#submit_button").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var _form = $(this).closest("form");
            var _formData = _form.serialize();


            $.post(_form.attr("action"), _formData, function (res) {

                if (!res.IsSuccess) {
                    var errors = "";
                    $.each(res.Errors, function (i, item) {
                        errors = errors + "<li>" + item + "</li>";
                    });
                    $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read <a href="#" class="alert-link">this important alert message</a>.</div>');
                }
                else {
                    //No errors. May be redirect ?
                }
            });

        });

    });

</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Upload(My_Models model)
        {
            return Json(new { IsSuccess = false });
        }
```

Removing JavaScript above the image arrive OK through model. Inseting the JavaScript above the image does not arrived. What is going on ?

The JavaScript above is only to show the message regarding to get image.

Comment: serialize alone will not send your file. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38703182/cannot-bind-form-data-and-uploaded-file-in-controller/38703844#38703844

Comment: You need to use `FormData` to upload files using ajax. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) (and you not using `BeginForm()` - your using `$.post()` to submit the form!)

Comment: Does not work, error javascript: ncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation