# C# ASP.NET MVC 5 ajax.beginform not able to upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to upload a file using `Ajax.BeginForm()` in ASP.NET MVC 5.2.

View:

```
@model EventsImages
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "EventsImages", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnComplete = "completeForm(xhr, status,'listDialog1')" }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form", @role = "form" }))
    {
       <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
          ...
          <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" />
          <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn" />
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(EventsImages eventsImages, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
```

The problem is that `HttpPostedFileBase` upload is always null.

I know this problem is mentioned several times but I couldn't find a solution, or a workaround.

Comment: You cannot upload files with the AjaxHelper. Here is how to upload files with ajax https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc.

Comment: While I believe Jasen is correct, the link is a non-mvc way to upload files.  Look for another answer on SO.  The following is more inline with the MVC way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38703844/209259.